# Angular datatables with filter column width

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I tried to set width for column in angular datatables  with filters.
But width of the column not changed.

I try following

```
   var columnsSpecification = [
      {
          type: 'text',
          bRegex: true,
          bSmart: true
      }, {
          type: 'text',
          bRegex: true,
          sWidth:"90px"}];


    $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
      .withBootstrap()
      .withOption('scrollX', '700%')
      .withOption('scrollY', height + 'px')
      .withOption('oLanguage', { "sEmptyTable": " " })
      .withOption('lengthMenu', [[-1, 1000, 100, 50, 25, 10], ['All', 1000, 100, 50, 25, 10]])
      .withOption('paging', false)
      .withOption('bInfo',false)
      .withColumnFilter({          
      aoColumns:columnsSpecification 
  })
  .withTableTools('/Content/DataTables/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf')
  .withTableToolsButtons(['xls']);
```

In html file I tried this:

```
   <table id="table-machines" datatable="ng" class="table table-striped" dt-options="dtOptions">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th style="width: 90px !important">Value</th>                
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="m in records>
            <td>{{m.name}}</td>
            <td style="width: 90px !important">{{m.Value}}</td>                
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

But Value column another zise rather I setted.

I'v found, that if there is not filter - all fine.

How can I set table width and preserve filters?

Comment: Try adding `.withOption('autoWidth', false)`.

Comment: I'v tryed it, it still not working.

Comment: For me neither, is there a bug in the new version?

Answer (score 9):

```
vm.dtColumns = [
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID').withOption('width', '5%')
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the option `width` in your `columnDefs` option:

```
vm.dtColumnDefs = [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(1).withOption('width', '90px')
  ];
```

See this [example](http://codepen.io/l-lin/pen/xwGNNW?editors=101).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found the solution for avoiding datatables overwrite bootstrap columns width definitions:

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withOption('autoWidth', false)
```

It was as easy as put that name and set to false... but it in the API doesn't appear to be available :(